# vb tab in vs.net

Tags: vb.net

is there any example for vb.tab appear in list box? as i can only display one data only.
i want to show both employer id number and the name.

example:

50 Alex

Below are my coding show only the employer name :

```
Dim qryUserlst As String = "SELECT emp_name FROM employer Where emp_name like '" & txtEmpName.Text & "%' ORDER BY emp_name ASC "
    daUserlst.SelectCommand = New OdbcCommand(qryUserlst, conn)

    Dim cb As OdbcCommandBuilder = New OdbcCommandBuilder(daUserlst)

    daUserlst.Fill(dsUserlst, "employer") 'fill dataset with data
    Dim dtUserlst As DataTable = dsUserlst.Tables("employer")

    Try
        If dsUserlst.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            lstEmpName.DataSource = dtUserlst
            lstEmpName.DisplayMember = "emp_name"
            lstEmpName.Visible = True
        Else
            lstStkCat.Visible = False
        End If

    Catch ex As OdbcException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Fix it! -- or it's only a matter of time until someone pwns your server.

Comment: Try putting `';DROP TABLE employer;--` in your txtEmpName textbox... or don't, if you value your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the same pattern/code setup that you have, simply change your SQL statement to concatenate the two columns to make a new column for display. The SQL syntax may vary, depending on your RDBMS. Below is SQL Server specific.

```
SELECT empname + ' ' + LTRIM(STR(empid)) as EmpDisplay FROM employer......
```

Then bind to your list using that new column:

```
lstEmpName.DisplayMember = "EmpDisplay"
```

Comment: Figure out your communication errors, try the code above, and let us know how it goes.